# find Missing ID in table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in table like below:

```
Primary_id  Serial_ID   PRIMARY_ID  SECONDARY_ID    queue_ID
1   100 58  89  Q1428291
2   100 58  89  Q1428281
3   100 58  89  Q1428293
4   100 89  58  Q1428293
5   100 89  58  Q1428291
6   100 89  58  Q1428000281
7   200 16  28  Q1433144
8   200 16  28  Q1431953
9   200 16  28  Q1432397
10  200 16  28  Q1431921
11  200 28  16  Q1433144
12  200 28  16  Q1432397
13  200 28  16  Q1431921
```

We have primary_ID and Secondary_ID column. for serial_ID 100 we have 3 primary and 3 secondary records ..If you see the data Primary_ID become secondary and secondary become primary(3 each).but for serial_id 200 we have 4 primary records but 3 secondar  records..

I want such records which have these kind of mismatch. Please assist

Comment: (1) You have two columns called `primary_id`.  (2) The results *as a text table* would make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the same number of rows for each primary/secondary combination on a `serial_id`.  If that is correct, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select serial_id
from (select serial_id, primary_id, secondary_id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by serial_id, primary_id, secondary_id
     ) ps
group by serial_id
having min(cnt) <> max(cnt);
```

Comment: Perfect!!Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Gordon, We need to insert the missing row also.Please suggest